# How to show these class of morphisms are perfect

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

In Lurie's book "Higher Topos Theory", a class $\mathsf{W}$ of morphisms in a category $\mathcal{A}$  is called perfect if

1. Every isomorphism belongs to $\mathsf{W}$.
2. it satisfies "2 out of 3 property".
3. $\mathsf{W}$ is stable under filtered colimit.
4. There exists a small subset $\mathsf{W}_0\subset\mathsf{W}$ such that every morphism belonging to $\mathsf{W}$ can be obtained as a filtered colimit of morphisms belonging to $\mathsf{W}_0$.

I can't show the class of isomorphism in $\mathsf{Set}$ is perfect because of the axiom 4. I think the class $\mathsf{W}$ does not form a small set. But I don't have any idea how to take a set of isomorphisms $\mathsf{W}_0$ to generate every isomorphisms.

And how about the case of the category of simplicial sets $\mathsf{Set}_\Delta$ with weak homotopy equivalences?

Comment: For isomorphisms in $\text{Set}$, take $W_0$ to consist of isomorphisms between (a skeleton of) finite sets.

Comment: You mean every set is a filtered colimit of the diagram of its finite subsets and so every isomorphism is induced by the isomorphisms between finite sets, right?

Comment: The two halves of your statement are true but there is a little bit of work to be done to get from one to the other. Also, the statement is true for weak equivalences of simplicial sets as well, but that requires a lot more work: see [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/19/30-19abs.html).

Comment: It seems that it uses the fact that $\mathsf{Set}_\Delta$ has Kan model structure. But in HTT, he uses this fact to get Kan model structure. Isn't it able to deduce that without using model structure?